# How to open the same file again in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In javascript I have an input tag that when user clicks they can select file from the local file system.  However I am unable to trigger the event to load the file a second time.  The open file dialog windows pops up but the onChange event (handleFiles) never gets fired if I select the same file again.  Is there a way to over come this?

I'm guessing since the file and path never changed, then the event onChange will never trigger.  However I do want it to trigger the event regardless if its the same or not. So basically always do it.

HTML

```
    <li><div data-dojo-attach-event="click: openForm" data-dojo-attach-point="open" >
        <input type="file" data-dojo-attach-point="fileLoader" data-dojo-attach-event="change: handleFiles" style="display:none" />
        <img data-dojo-attach-point="openIcon" width="35" height="35" src="formsdesigner/app/editor/icons/Open.png" /></div></li>
```

JS functions (Dojo)

```
    openForm: function () {

        this.fileLoader.click();
        return false;
    },

    handleFiles: function (evt) {
        var IOC = ioController;
        console.log("got files");

        var file = evt.target.files[0];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            var contents = e.target.result;
            console.log(contents);

            IOC._loadForm(contents);
        };



    },
```

**FYI:** unfortunately my code is in Dojo, but I just wanted to show how I attached the events to my HTML nodes and what the functions do.  This is not a Dojo specific issue.

Comment: I don't know Dojo, but if you don't actually change the file then it makes some sense that there wouldn't be a `change` event. Does Dojo support an  `input` event?

Comment: @apsillers yes that's what I think as well.  Don't worry about the dojo parts, is there another way in javascript to always trigger the event regardless?  Like is there an onAlways event?

Comment: how about blur?

Comment: @epascarello no effect, when I click open on the file dialog, nothing happens with or without the same file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do this on file input element click event:

```
var fileInput = document.querySelector(".fileinput");
fileInput.addEventListener("click", function() {
    fileInput.value = null;
}
```

then you can select the same file again.

Comment: thank you, this worked, In my code above - in openForm function i set this.fileLoader.value to null before I trigger the click() event on it.

Answer (score 0):

The File input box is basically just a text field with path to the file on users machine (in most browsers anyway). Since the path doesn't change, `onChange` event is indeed not fired.

Binding `click` event as suggested should work.